# Specific a div area not to do the function using js/ jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

Now I have a webpage function that is  trigger in the window everywhere exclude the restrictArea. I have make the restrictArea overlap the main content. How can I specific this area do not trigger the function? I tried `e.preventDefault();` but it seems that does not work.
Thanks

```
$(document).swipe(function(){
    ...............
};


$('#flip').swiperight(function(e){
 e.stopPropagation();
 e.preventDefault();
});
```

Update: all the revelant code:

**css:**

```
*
{
 -webkit-user-select: none;         /* disable auto selection (select/selectall when long tap)*/
 -webkit-touch-callout: none;       /* disable magnifier*/
}
#flip
{       
position:absolute;
background-color:red;
z-index:10;
height: 100%;
width:60%;
left:20%;
}
```

**js:**

```
    $(document).swipeleft(function(){
        //check the case when popup and thumbnail slide bar is not exist
        if ($("#popup").length == '0' && parseInt($('#all_pages').css('left')) != '0'){  
            if (checkOrientation (orientation)== 'landscape'){
                    var pageLand = $('#book').turn('view');
                    pageLand = pageLand[1];
                    if (pageLand + 1 < countImage && pageLand != '0')
                        $('#book').turn('page', pageLand + 1);
            }
            else{
                    var pagePort = $('#book').turn('page');
                    if (pagePort + 1 < countImage && pagePort != '0')
                        $('#book').turn('page', pagePort + 1);
            }
        }
    });

    $(document).swiperight(function(){
        //check the case when popup and thumbnail slide bar is not exist
        if ($("#popup").length == '0' && parseInt($('#all_pages').css('left')) != '0'){ 
            if (checkOrientation (orientation)== 'landscape'){
                    var pageLand = $('#book').turn('view');
                    pageLand = pageLand[0];
                    if (pageLand - 1 > 0)
                        $('#book').turn('page', pageLand - 1);
            }
            else{
                    var pagePort = $('#book').turn('page');
                    if (pagePort - 1 > 0)
                        $('#book').turn('page', pagePort - 1);
            }
        }
    });


    $('#flip').swiperight(function(e){
      alert ('test');
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    });

    $('#flip').swipeleft(function(e){
      alert ('test');
      e.stopPropagation();
      e.preventDefault();
    });
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the following code. You need to stop the bubbling of the event from the child node to the parent document.

```
$('#restrictArea').swipe(function(e){
  e.stopPropagation();
  e.preventDefault();
});
```

Comment: It seems the function still trigger when I swipe on restrict area, may be it is because I am using safari browser on IPAD? How to fix it? thanks

Comment: Can you post the link of the plugin you are using. The swipe plugin I had used takes configuration object as params like swipeLeft and swipeRight etc.

Comment: sure , I use jquery mobile event

Comment: ok, so the issue might be that the dimensions of #restrictArea is not adequate and the swipe event is getting triggered on nearby elements - which gets bubbled to the document.

Comment: I have posted all the revelant code here  , the size of restricted area should be sufficient as you can see it is 60% of whole page width and the height is 100%. Please have a look. Thanks

Comment: posting code here is not a good idea - its not possible to check the parent of the element etc - can you create a fiddle, repro it there and post the link? http://jsfiddle.net/

Comment: It is quite tiresome work, would you mind teaching me how to check? currently the <div id = "flip"></div> is inside body and not contain in any  other <div>

Comment: use some silly way to complete my job,by  just checking event.target.id;

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `$(document)` can't you bind .swipe on some `DIV` (which might be height/width 100%)? Then you simply make `#restrictArea` with a higher `z-index` than the `DIV` and you should be fine.

Also, in your code, you try to do preventDefault, but the variable e is not defined/passed in your function.

Comment: Thanks, cutting the whole window into several div is much complicated in my case  so I am thinking the way to specific the restrict area

Answer (score 0):

In your code you don't have your function closed properly:

```
  $(document).swipe(function(){
   ...............
  });
 //^-----------you missed out this

  $('#restrictArea').swipe(function(e){
                   //---------------^-----------you missed out this
      e.preventDefault();
  });
//-^---------------------------------this too
```

jQuery doesn't have a `.swipe` handler but jQuery mobile has so your code should be like this:

```
$(document).bind("pageinit", function(event, data) {
    $('#restrictArea').swipe(function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
    });
});
```